# onInput is not being triggered after the enter is pressed in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, input, contenteditable, mozilla

I've created a contenteditable div in my react component and when I press the enter inside the div and try to type something the function onInput is not being triggered. That's only case in **Mozilla**. Also when I type enter or backspace it works but doesn't work if I want to type some normal letters. Tnx for help:

```
<div
    id={Constants.FREE_FORMULA__TEXTAREA_INPUT__ID}
    contentEditable="true"
    name="value"
    className="slds-textarea formula-container"
    type={Constants.FREE_FORMULA__TEXTAREA_INPUT__ID}
     value={text}
     onInput={(e) => {
        this.handleOnChange(e);
       }}
      onPaste={e => this.handleOnPaste(e)}
      onBlur={() => {
        const textArea = document.getElementById(Constants.FREE_FORMULA__TEXTAREA_INPUT__ID);
        textArea.focus();
        }}
   />
```

Comment: This might have something to do with React's [`SyntheticEvent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html).

Comment: How about `keypress` instead of `input`?

Comment: @YaakovAinspan please tell me more :D

Comment: @ScottMarcus I've tried that but also doesn't work.

Comment: Using the `keyUp` event seems to work in firefox

Comment: See [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-sky-doysh?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

Sveto, StackOverflow has not given me permission to comment yet, so I will sadly have to put this into an answer.

Have you tried using `onChange={(e) => this.handleOnChange(e)}`?

Although React supposedly treats onInput and onChange almost the exact same, it seems to me that onChange is more consistent and sustainable. Try it out and tell me if you see a change in your code.

Comment: Tnx for the answer but it doesn't work :(